# jQuery validate still redirects and opens form action path

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-forms-plugin

jQuery opens my form action instead of submitting the form without changing of page. What I'm working now is, I don't want the page to refresh when submitting the form because I want to integrate a progress bar when it's submitting/loading. Thanks for helping.

Here's my jQuery for validating and redirecting:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
            $('document').ready(function(){
            $('#form').validate({
                rules:{
                    "fname":{
                        required:true,
                        maxlength:40
                    },
                    "lname":{
                        required:true,
                        maxlength:40
                    },
                    "mobile":{
                        required:true,
                        number: true
                    },
                    "address":{
                        required:true
                    },
                    "year":{
                        required:true
                    },
                    "month":{
                        required:true
                    },
                    "day":{
                        required:true
                    },
                    "files": {
                        accept:"jpg,png,jpeg,gif"
                    },
                    "vid": {
                        accept: "ogg|ogv|avi|mpe?g|mov|wmv|flv|mp4"
                    }},
                messages:{
                    "fname":{
                        required:"First Name is required"
                    },
                    "lname":{
                        required:"Last Name is required"
                    },
                    "mobile":{
                        required:"Mobile is required"
                    },
                    "address":{
                        required:"Address is required"
                    },
                    "files":{
                        accept: "Please choose a valid image file (jpg/png/jpeg/gif)"
                    },
                    "vid" : {
                        accept: "Please choose a valid video file (ogg/ogv/avi/mpg/mpeg/mov/flv/mp4)"
                    }}
                    submitHandler: function(form){
                        $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                            target: '#preview',
                            success: function() {
                            //$('form').find('input[type=text], select,input[type=file]').val('');

                        //  }
                        });
                        }
                    })
                });
```

Here's a part of my form:

```
<form id="form" name="form" action="submit_video.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

</form>
```

Comment: I changed if(isset($_POST[submit])) to if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") in my submit.php

Sorry for another stupid question.

Answer (score 0):

**Quote OP:**

> *"jQuery opens my form action instead of submitting the form without changing of page."*

Syntax errors will block the plugin from functioning and the default form action will happen on submit.

---

Your code...

```
}}
submitHandler: function(form){
    $(form).ajaxSubmit({
        target: '#preview',
        success: function() {
        //$('form').find('input[type=text], select,input[type=file]').val('');
    //  }
    });
    }
```

You have at least two syntax errors inside your `.validate()` call.

1)  Inside `submitHandler`, un-comment the closing brace, `}`, for the `success` callback function of `ajaxSubmit()`.

See my comments...

```
submitHandler: function(form){
    $(form).ajaxSubmit({
        target: '#preview',
        success: function() {
            //$('form').find('input[type=text], select,input[type=file]').val('');
        } // <-- you need this brace to close the success callback function
    });   // <-- close ajaxSubmit
}         // <-- close submitHandler
```

2)  You are also missing a comma to separate your `messages` option from your `submitHandler` callback.  This syntax error will prevent the plugin from operating and ***your form will submit using the default form action***.

```
}},  // <-- you need this comma here
submitHandler: function(form){
```

I strongly recommend that you properly format and indent your code so that syntax errors are easier to spot.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('document').ready(function(){
        $('#form').validate({
            rules: {
                "fname": {
                    required: true,
                    maxlength: 40
                },
                // etc.
            },
            messages: {
                "fname": {
                    required: "First Name is required"
                },
                // etc.
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                // your function
            }
        }); // close .validate()
    });  // close document.ready
<script>
```